# Having difficulties locating a problem in the for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am writing a program where a user inputs the name of contestants and buys like a ticket for a competition. I am trying to figure out the percent chance for each contestant to win but for some reason its returning zero, here's the code

```
for(int i = 0; i < ticPurch.size(); i++){
    totalTics = ticPurch[i] + totalTics;                                              //Figuring out total amount of ticket bought
}
    cout << totalTics;

for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++){
    cout << "Contenstant "  << "   Chance of winning " << endl; 
    cout << names[i] << "   " << ((ticPurch.at(i))/(totalTics)) * 100 << " % " << endl; //Figuring out the total chance of winning 

}
    ticPurch is a vector of the the tickets each contestant bought and names is a vector for the contestants name. For some reason the percent is always returning zero and I don't know why

 return 0;
```

Comment: what type is `totalTics`? And what type is `ticPurch.at(i)`? Hint: if they're both `int`, the result of that division will also be an `int`.

Comment: What is ticPurch? What is totalTics? If you are trying to divide integers, you'll get an integer. 3/4 gives 0. Use `double` if that is the case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dividing an integer by an integer [gives you an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602827/560648), by truncation of the fractional part.

Since your values are less than one, your result will always be zero.

You could cast an operand to a floating-point type to get the calculation you wanted:

```
(ticPurch.at(i) / (double)totalTics) * 100
```

Then probably round this result, since you seem to want whole number results:

```
std::floor((ticPurch.at(i) / (double)totalTics) * 100)
```

My preferred approach, which avoids floating-point entirely (always nice!), is to multiply to the resolution of your calculation *first*:

```
(ticPurch.at(i) * 100) / totalTics
```

This will always round *down*, so be aware of that if you decided to go with, say, `std::round` (or `std::ceil`) instead of `std::floor` in the example above. Arithmetic trickery can mimic those if needs be.

Now, instead of e.g. `(3/5) * 100` (which is `0*100` (which is `0`)), you have e.g. `(3*100)/5` (which is `300/5` (which is `60`)).

Comment: I was always taught to use a `static_cast` here. Is there any reason to prefer the C-style cast?

Comment: @scohe001 Not really, I'm just being lazy. Honestly though in the case of int->double it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Meh fair enough